Comparing text fields that contain dates in Google Sheets
I am getting the dates in the following format:
5.9.2024. so d.m.yyyy.
and I need to use that field in the query formula in order to check if that date falls between two dates (e.g. >=5.9.2024. and <=12.9.2025. are the values of the cells for the date range).
I am struggling to convert the text cell to date so that I can do this comparison.

I tried all different formulas for text to date conversion, but nothing works.
=query(A4:B, "select Col1 where Col2>='"&$A2&"'AND Col2<='"&$B2&"'")


You may try the following formula-
=--TEXTJOIN("/",1,CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(A1,"."),2,1,3))

Then apply your desired date format to cells.

To convert entire column, use-
=MAP(A1:A,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="",,--TEXTJOIN("/",1,CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(x,"."),2,1,3)))))



Correcting format of date for comparison
It seems that you are having issues in converting the string that is the reason why you are encountering issues during the comparison.
Try to convert your dates using this formula.
=LET(dates, SPLIT(A1, "."), dd, CHOOSECOLS(dates, 1), mm, CHOOSECOLS(dates,2), yyyy, CHOOSECOLS(dates,3), DATE(yyyy,mm,dd))

Before doing any comparison it should work as expected.
You can also try this formula to process multiple rows.
Use BYROW and place the formula within a LAMBDA function.
=BYROW(A1:A7, LAMBDA(r, LET(dates, SPLIT(r, "."), dd, CHOOSECOLS(dates, 1), mm, CHOOSECOLS(dates,2), yyyy, CHOOSECOLS(dates,3), DATE(yyyy,mm,dd))))

Sample Output:

Note: This is for converting your string to a Date that can be used in the comparison part of the formula. If you need more information on how to work with this formula, please feel free to ask in the comments.
Reference:
Date

An alternative to correct the dates and dump the Columns A and B on the sheet the formula in cell D4 is:
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A4:B, IF(B4:B<>"",REGEXREPLACE(B4:B,"(\d+).(\d+)\.(\d+)\.","$2/$1/$3"),"")},"Select Col1, Col3 Where Col1 Is Not Null"))

.


To get dates directly from you first column, try-
=LET(x,CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(A2," "),-1),--TEXTJOIN("/",1,CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(x,"."),2,1,3)))

For entire column, try-
=MAP(A2:A,LAMBDA(z,IF(z="",,LET(x,CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(z," "),-1),--TEXTJOIN("/",1,CHOOSECOLS(SPLIT(x,"."),2,1,3))))))


